# How to assign one dimension of a 2d array to a new 1d array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access

I need to be able to create a newarray and assign it to another2darray(atsomeelement)

Example

```
array1(0) = 1
array1(1) = 2
```

and now

```
array2(0) = array1
```

and therefore

```
array2(0)(0) = 1
array2(0)(1) = 2
```

Now I want to take make a new array and assign 1d of the array2 to it.

```
newarray = array2(0)
```

and therefore

```
newarray(0) = 1
newarray(1) = 1
```

I cannot do this in VBA code.
Code snippet below, works if you comment out the last section where I try and assign `array2(1)` to `arraynew`.

```
Function test()
    Dim array1(0 To 20) As String
    Dim array2(0 To 5) As Variant
    Dim count As Integer

    For count = 0 To UBound(array1)
     array1(count) = count
    Next count

    'now that array1 is filled i want to insert it into array2(1)
    array2(1) = array1

    ' test
    MsgBox (array2(1)(3))

    'now i want to create a new string array and assign it to array2(1)
    Dim arraynew(0 To 20) As String
    arraynew = array2(1)
    'this is what fails. 

End Function
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8482759/641067

Comment: Note that, technically, what you have is *not* a 2d array but an array of arrays. That's something different. (There are also real 2d arrays in VBA.)

Answer (score 8):

You cannot assign to a fixed-size array. Declare it as a dynamic one.

```
Dim arraynew() As String
arraynew = array2(1)
```