# Is it possible to assign values to array without looping? VBA

Tags: vba

I'm a bit new to VBA and don't understand how do I assign specific values into array, not the range. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Dim toDel(8) As Integer
Set toDel() = Array(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12)
```

But it returns me error. So can I somehow insert a hole array into array without looping through each element? Like we do it in python just array = array

Comment: `Dim toDel As variant`

Comment: and `toDel = Array(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12)`

Comment: `Array()` is a function that returns a Variant array, so you can only assign its result to a Variant. If you had a function that returns a strongly typed integer array, you could assign that to an integer array variable, provided it was declared as a [dynamic array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844294/11683). You should not use `Set`.

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
Option Explicit
Sub whatever()
    Dim toDel As Variant
    toDel = Array(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12)
End Sub
```